# Lights Not Producing Expected Effects on 3D Model in Three.js

Tags: three.js, 3d, react-three-fiber, 3d-model, react-three-drei

I'm currently working on a 3D scene using Three.js, where I've incorporated a 3D model using the `@react-three/fiber` and `@react-three/drei` libraries. The model renders correctly, but I'm encountering issues with getting the lights to produce the expected effects on the model.

Issue Details:

1. Model Rendering: The 3D model is rendering correctly, and I can see it in the scene as expected.
2. Lighting Problem: However, the lights ( and ) that I've added to the scene are not producing the desired lighting effects on the model.
3. Configuration: I've configured the lights within the  component, which is a child of the  component. The lights are placed correctly in the hierarchy.
4. Attempted Solutions: I've tried adjusting light intensities, positions, and shadow properties to see if that resolves the issue. I've also checked the material properties of the model to ensure it should react to lighting.
5. Debugging: I've checked the browser console for error messages or warnings, but I haven't found anything related to the lights that could explain the issue.

this is snippet of my code

What did you try and what were you expecting?

Attempts Made:
I've been working on a Three.js scene using the @react-three/fiber and @react-three/drei libraries. I've integrated a 3D model of a computer into the scene using the useGLTF hook, and the model is rendering as expected. However, I'm having trouble getting the lights to produce the desired effects on the model.

Lighting Configuration:
In the  component, I've added a  and a  as children of a  that holds the 3D model. I've adjusted the properties of the lights, including intensity, ground color, and position, to see if I can get the lights to illuminate the model.

Expected Effects:
I was expecting the lights to create realistic lighting and shading on the 3D model. Specifically, I wanted the  to provide overall ambient lighting with a black ground color, and the  to simulate a localized light source.

Result:
Despite my efforts to configure the lights, they are not producing the expected effects on the 3D model. The model itself renders correctly, but it appears to be unaffected by the lights I've added.

Debugging Steps:

I've verified that the lights are correctly placed as children of the  containing the model.
I've adjusted the light intensities and positions to see if that would have any effect.
I've checked the browser console for errors or warnings related to the lights, but I haven't found any issues there.
Question:
I'm not sure what might be causing the lights to not work as expected. Could there be any specific factors or considerations I'm overlooking? Any insights or guidance on how to properly configure the lights to achieve the desired lighting effects on my 3D model would be greatly appreciated.

```
tyimport {Suspense, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber';
import { OrbitControls, Preload, useGLTF } from '@react-three/drei';
import CanvasLoader from '../Loader';


const Computers = () => {
  const computer = useGLTF('./desktop_pc/scene.gltf')

  return (
    <mesh>
      <hemisphereLight intensity={0.15}
      groundColor="black"/>
      <pointLight intensity={1}/>
      <primitive 
        object={computer.scene}
        scale={0.75}
        position={[0, -4.25, -1.5] }
        rotation={[-0.01, -0.2, -0.1]}
      />
    </mesh>
  )
}

const ComputersCanvas = () => {
  return (
    <Canvas 
      frameLoop="demand"
      shadows
      camera={{ position: [20, 3, 5], fov: 25 }}
      gl={{ preserveDrawingBuffer: true}}
    >
      <Suspense>
        <OrbitControls 
          enableZoom={false}
          maxPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
          minPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
        />
        <Computers />
      </Suspense>

      <Preload all/>
    </Canvas>
  )
}

export default ComputersCanvas;pe here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the intensity of hemisphereLight (Intensity of 5 worked best for me). Set the groundColor to "black" for better display of your computer scene.